# An interesting Bound for Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, distribution-tails

I have seen the following bound somewhere, but could not find it.

> Let $n$ be an non negative integer and $X \sim Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$. Show that there exists an abosolute constant $c > 0$, such that $Pr\big[X \leq \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\big] \geq c$.

Note that $\mathbb{E}X = \frac{n}{2}$, so the above lemma says that $X$ can not be too close to the mean. Can someone give a reference to this result, or an outline of a proof?

Thanks

Comment: The good thing with the binomial distribution is that its tails are quite explicit. You should be able to prove this bound using simple estimates on binomial coefficients. (Alternatively, this can be deduced from the central limit theorem.)

Comment: Ok, I found the reference. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X13000617, Lemma 3. The constant in the Lemma is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: @md5 Can you please elaborate? My motivation for the question is to see if similar results holds for negatively correlated random variables (for example Hypergeometric distribution).

Comment: Let $p_n$ be the probability you are interested in. By the CLT, $p_n$ converges to $K>0$ as $n\to\infty$, so there is some $N$ such that $p_n\ge K/2$ for all $n\ge N$. Then you can take $c=\min(p_1, \ldots, p_N, K/2)$ (check that indeed $c>0$). This argument does not give the best constant, but you can refine it using, say, Berry-Esseen.

Comment: As for negatively correlated random variables, you can't get anticoncentration in general (just take a sequence of constant random variables). For explicit distributions such as hypergeometric, you can probably prove bounds using estimates on binomial coefficients in a way similar to the reference you pointed to.

Comment: @md5, thanks for the comment. Indeed Berry-Esseen can be used

Comment: As for the Hypergeometric distribution, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199108/lower-bound-on-the-tail-of-the-hypergeometric-distribution may shed some light.

Comment: Another way using explicit estimates on binomial coefficients: Note that $\frac 1{2^n}\binom n{n/2} \sim \sqrt{\frac 2{\pi n}}$ by Stirling's formula. This is the largest term in the binomial distribution, so ${\rm Pr}\left[\frac n2-\frac 12\sqrt{\frac n2} < X \le \frac n2\right]$ is at most $\left\lceil \frac 12\sqrt{\frac n2}\right\rceil\sqrt{\frac 2{\pi n}}$, which is less than (and bounded away from) $\frac 12$. In fact this should give you $c = \frac 12\left(1-\sqrt{\frac 1\pi}\right) \approx 0.22$.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is the proof from aforementioned paper.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am presenting a proof using [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) .

$X$ can be thought of as sum of unbiased Bernoulli random variables $X_i$, $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $P[X_i=1] = \frac{1}{2} = P[X_i=0]$.

Now define $X^\prime_i = X_i -\frac{1}{2}$. We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_i] &= 0\\
\sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}[X_i^{\prime 2}] &= \frac{1}{4} > 0\\
\rho = \mathbb{E}[\vert X_i^\prime\vert^3] = \frac{1}{8} < \infty 
\end{align*}
Define $Y = \frac{X}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} = \frac{2X}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sqrt{n}$.

Berry-Esseen them implies that
\begin{align*}
\vert F_Y(x) - \Phi(x)\vert \leq \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}} = \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
Where $C$ is an absolute constant $< 1$ and $F_Y()$ is the cdf of $Y$. Now observe that $X \leq \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ is same as $Y \leq \sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So

\begin{align*}
F_Y(\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) \geq \Phi(\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) - \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
Since $n\geq 1$, the second term is $C$ and $\Phi(\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) \geq \Phi(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$, a constant and we are done.

I think this justifies the $\sqrt{n}$ term as  well. Also, I this the reverse inequality can also be proven in a similar manner, i.e.

> $Pr\big[X\geq \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\big] \geq c^\prime$, for some absolute constant $c^\prime$.